# pthread setup in php 7.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: php, pthreads

I am using php 7.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I have to implement multi-threading in php with help of pthread. 
Several method I tried but every time getting

```
configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

Even I tried to install php from scratch but could not success.

I was follow following website steps :
 https://www.rapidspike.com/blog/php7-pthreads/

Please help.

Comment: what is the output of `php -v` ? you may need to compile pthread it self from source and define your php target version to be the php-zts version

Comment: php -v  output is follow :

  PHP 7.0.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2018 10:01:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans

Comment: as you can see, you are trying to install your pecl package for the ( NTS ) version

Comment: what is the output of `locate bin/php`

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> php -v output is follow : PHP 7.0.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
>   (cli) (built: Jul 25 2018 10:01:10) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend
>   Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.0.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1,
>   Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies with Xdebug v2.6.0,
>   Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans

You are trying to install a pecl package against the invalid version of PHP which is in your case ( NTS ) instead of ( ZTS ).

To get rid of this you will need one of this possible actions:-

1- Install pecl package for a specific PHP version.

```
pecl -d php_suffix=X.X-zts install pthreads
```

---

2- Update the default version for your environment.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/phpX.X-zts
```

**Note & Warning:** this means that *all* of your php terminal applications will be running under the ZTS version which may cause some unexpected behaviors.

However you can toggle your PHP versions back after installation.

---

3 - Compile phtread from source and define the target PHP version (complicated but preferred).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads.git
$ cd pthreads/
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/php-zts/bin/php-config
$ make
$ make install
```

You will may need to update alternatives also for `phpize`

```
update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize-zts
```

---

**Note:** All of PHP versions that had been mentioned in this answer may be different from setup to setup, So you may need to check your PHP version name&path using `locate bin/php`

Comment: I was tried to install php ZTS but got following error :
sudo apt -y install php7.0-zts php7.0-zts-common php7.0-zts-xml php7.0-zts-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-zts
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-zts' ...
@hassan Please help me.

Comment: @PrabhuNandanKumar its better to compile php from source and enable zts while the compilation

Comment: I tried lot but in ubuntu 18.04 unable to enable zts . If your end any specific idea how to enable zts please let me know.